# Length returns the value of the total siblings and won't update if a sibling is removed. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a page loads for the first time, the .length on siblings returns let's say 3. Then a "click" event triggers a post and on success removes a sibling and the .length is called again, but it keep returning 3.

Please note that each sibling is remove via a "click" event at random time and not within the same loop.

Example: (hand-coded here, but should explain the behavior)

```
<ul id="un33k">
    <li><a class="clicked" href="/link/1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="clicked" href="/link/2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="clicked" href="/link/3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="clicked" href="/link/4">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var total_li = $('#un33k').children().length; // 3 (test only)

    $('a.clicked').click(function () {
        var me = this;
        $.post('somelink', {...}, function(data, status) { // assuming success
            var new_total_li =  $(me).closest('li').siblings().length; // 3, good
            var parent = $(me).closest('li').parent() // can't hardcode id
            $(me).closest('li').remove(); // assuming the clicked li is gone now
            new_total_li =  $(parent).children().length; // 3, but should be 2 now?
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

Even a click few minutes later, would still show 3. Why?

**Update: Copying the actual code here:**

This line is the culprit (*console.log($(me).closest('li').siblings().length*) which shows the same initial number no matter how many siblings are deleted.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.get2post').click(function () {
        var me = this;
        var url = $(me).attr('href');
        if ($(me).hasClass('confirm')){
            if(!window.confirm("Are you sure?")){
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($(me).hasClass('deletion')){
            var postdata = {ajax: 'true' };
            $.post(url, postdata, function(data, status) {
                if (status == 'success'){
                    $(me).closest('li').hide('slow', function(){ $(me).remove(); });
                    console.log($(me).closest('li').siblings().length) // problem
                }
            }, "json");
       }
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(me).closest('li').siblings().length;` should return two, not three which is the number of sibling list items, not total list items. But even with that error, `$(parent).children().length` returns two for me.

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle demo of this](http://jsfiddle.net/rupw/M2sNr/1/). But it works for me.

Comment: Works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/97m9Q/. Are your links taking you away from the page?

Comment: Thanks folks, yeah, looking back at the code, I see that the actual delete is happening within a successful $.post block. Would that matter? I wish I could copy and paste the code in here ... but that is the only thing that jumps out at me now. thx.

Comment: @ValNeekman Absolutely that could matter. `$.post` sends an asynchronous request, so the response will/can happen at an unspecified time in the future, while code right now runs...right now. So the code right now doesn't know what will happen in the future. And you can paste the code here...edit your question and append it to the end.

Comment: @lan, Thank you for clearing that up, yeah, I updated the question to make it more relevant and added the .post. Now how can this be done I guess jsonp? Thx again.

Comment: @ValNeekman Added an answer. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the `$(me).remove();` line. That is removing the `<a>` element, because `me` refers to `this`, which is the `a.get2post` element. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish - remove the `<a>` or the `<li>`, but when you get the count from `$(me).closest('li').siblings().length`, you're referencing the `<li>` elements. Removing the `<a>` with `$(me).remove();` doesn't affect the collection of `<li>` elements. So you need to decide what you're meaning to remove and count in your situations.

Your workflow is like this: hide the parent `<li>`, remove the `<a>` being referenced, then get the count of `<li>` siblings. The `<li>` is never removed, so the count will always be the same, despite some being hidden.

Take a look at this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.get2post').click(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        var parent_li = me.closest("li");
        var url = "/echo/json/";//$(me).attr('href');
        if (me.hasClass('confirm')){
            if(!window.confirm("Are you sure?")){
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (me.hasClass('deletion')){
            var postdata = {stuff: 'stuff' };
            $.post(url, postdata, function(data, status) {
                if (status == 'success'){
                    parent_li.hide('slow', function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    console.log(parent_li.siblings().length) // problem
                }
            }, "json");
       }
       return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CTC3J/

It actually removes the target `<li>` element after it's done being hidden.

Comment: You are 100% right, yeah, I needed to remove that <li> indeed. Thx.